# What iCloud data am I sharing with an app when I provide it with an app-specific password?

Tags: icloud, security, password, privacy

The [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397) states:

> Some apps made by developers other than Apple ask you to sign in with your Apple ID, so that the app can access information like mail, contacts, and calendars that you store in iCloud.

I find "like" to be a completely inappropriate word choice in this context due to its ambiguity. Can an app also access my photos, notes, and files using an app-specific password? I certainly consider those things to be "like" my mail, contacts, and calendars. Where is this documented?

Also, why on earth can't I choose which data to share when I create an app-specific password? I don't want a calendar service to have access to my mail and contacts (or any other data for that matter!).

Comment: “Like” here is synonymous with “for example.”  An app doesn’t *need* your Apple ID to access mail or photos, for example.  It can access it on your device (it will notify you if it wants to access Photos and will allow you allow/deny). It only need your credentials to access iCloud.

Comment: @Allan I think there is some additional confusion again due to Apple's poor choice of words. App-specific passwords are used by third-party services (referred to here as "the app"), not native iOS apps. In my case I signed up for Calendly and they requested an app-specific password to sync with my iCloud calendar. There is no iOS app involved that can request the fine-grained permissions you referenced. My question is about what data Calendly's servers can access from my iCloud account with an app-specific password.

Comment: There’s what they (app devs) disclose and what they actually access.  My rule of thumb is to assume they will have access to everything regardless of what they say (which is why I don’t use services like this)

Comment: @Allan That's certainly the safest assumption and generally my policy as well but I don't think it's unreasonable to assume that a clearly enumerated list should also be documented somewhere!

Comment: That would have to come from the dev as it would be impractical for Apple to maintain this ever changing list

Comment: @Allan If it is the case that all data in an iCloud account is accessible via an app-specific password then the documentation could and should just say as much. There's nothing impractical about providing this information to end-users.